# Mounting Clickhouse data directory to another partition: DB::Exception: Settings profile `default` not found

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to move clickhouse data directory to another partition `/dev/sdb1`. So here's what I've done:

```
sudo systemctl stop clickhouse-server
mv /var/lib/clickhouse /var/lib/clickhouse-orig
mkdir /var/lib/clickhouse
chown clickhouse:clickhouse /var/lib/clickhouse
mount -o user /dev/sdb1 /var/lib/clickhouse 
cp -Rv /var/lib/clickhouse-orig/* /var/lib/clickhouse/
chown -Rv clickhouse:clickhouse /var/lib/clickhouse
sudo systemctl start clickhouse-server
```

but it shows an error when it started:

```
Processing configuration file '/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml'.
Sending crash reports is disabled
Starting ClickHouse 21.6.4.26 with revision 54451, build id: 12B138DBA4B3F1480CE8AA18884EA895F9EAD439, PID 10431
starting up
OS Name = Linux, OS Version = 5.4.0-1044-gcp, OS Architecture = x86_64
Calculated checksum of the binary: 26864E69BE34BA2FCCE2BD900CF631D4, integrity check passed.
Setting max_server_memory_usage was set to 882.18 MiB (980.20 MiB available * 0.90 max_server_memory_usage_to_ram_ratio)
DB::Exception: Settings profile `default` not found
shutting down
Stop SignalListener thread
```

**EDIT**
apparently even without new partition it doesn't start, so probably the `config.xml` or the `macro.xml` is the culprit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check /var/lib/clickhouse/preprocessed_configs/users.xml file
it should contains XPath /yandex/profiles/default

```
apt-get install -y libxml2-utils
xmllint --xpath /yandex/profiles/default /var/lib/clickhouse/preprocessed_configs/users.xml
```

also, look to source configs `/etc/clickhouse-server/users.xml` and possible `/etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/*.xml` or `/etc/clickhouse-server/conf.d/*.xml`

Comment: yes, found the culprit, i'm using `config.xml` and `macro.xml` from docker compose, that are wrong (but it works on `docker-compose`), so I replace it with original `config.xml` with my own addition.